# Retrieve version number from file follow string

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I want to be able to retrieve a version number (n.n.n) from a file (yaml) that follows a string.

```
sdk: ">=0.2.4 <3.1.1"
version: ^2.3.1
sdk: flutter
version: 1.0.0+1
```

`sed -n '/version:/p sample.yaml`

which returns the line for the string provided "version:", I then piped this into another command `grep` to pattern match the line for the version number:

`sed -n '/version:/p sample.yaml | grep -oP '(\[0-9\]+).(\[0-9\]+).(\[0-9\]+)'`

I would like to see if there is a more efficient way to do this, and if string = 'sdk' from the example the returned value returns both when I would like to return a single value.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Regarding `I would like to return a single value` - which value and based on what criteria?

Comment: @HaiVu expected output: "I want to be able to retrieve a version number (n.n.n) from a file (yaml)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```sh
sed -nE 's/.*version:[^0-9]*([0-9][0-9.]*).*/\1/p' file
grep -oP 'version:\D*\K\d[\d.]*' file
```

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/RnLfgS):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='sdk: ">=0.2.4 <3.1.1"
version: ^2.3.1
sdk: flutter
version 1.0.0+1'
sed -nE 's/.*version:[^0-9]*([0-9][0-9.]*).*/\1/p' <<< "$s"
# => 2.3.1
grep -oP 'version:\D*\K\d[\d.]*' <<< "$s"
# => 2.3.1
```

The `version:\D*\K\d[\d.]*` *grep* regex matches `version:` substring, then any zero or more non-digits (with `\D*`), then omits the matched text (with `\K`) and then matches and returns a digit and then any zero or more digits or dots (with `\d[\d.]*`).

The `sed` POSIX ERE (see `-E` option enabling this regex flavor) pattern matches

- `.*` - any text
- `version:` - a fixed substring
- `[^0-9]*` - zero or more non-digits
- `([0-9][0-9.]*)` - Group 1 (`\1`): a digit and then zero or more digits or dots
- `.*` - any text.

The whole match is replaced with Group 1 value, the `p` flag prints the result of the successful substitution (`-n` suppresses default line output).

Answer (score 1):

Use `awk`

```
awk '/version:/ { 
    pos=match($2, /[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/);
    print substr($2, pos, RLENGTH); }' sample.yaml
```

`match()` returns the position in the field where the regexp is found, and sets `RLENGTH` to its length.

Comment: thank you, this didn't work for `version: 1.0.0+1` as it returned `1.0.01`.  Apologies I didn't realise i had missed the : in the last version in the sample section.